# Implementing Hive UNION in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a SQL from a file and run it inside a Pyspark job. The SQL is structured as below:

```
select <statements>
sort by rand()
limit 333333 
UNION ALL
select <statements>
sort by rand()
limit 666666
```

here is the error I am getting when I run it:

> pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input 'UNION'
>   expecting {, '.', '[', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE',
>   RLIKE, 'IS', EQ, '<=>', '<>', '!=', '<', LTE, '>', GTE, '+', '-', '*',
>   '/', '%', 'DIV', '&', '|', '^'}

Is this because *UNION* *ALL/UNION* is not supported by spark SQL or something to do with the with parsing gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark and Hive supports UNION in the sql statement.
I am able to run the following hive statement

```
(SELECT * from x ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 50)
UNION
(SELECT * from y ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 50)
```

In pyspark you can also do this

```
df1=spark.sql('SELECT * from x ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 50')
df2=spark.sql('SELECT * from y ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 50')
df=df1.union(df2)
```

Comment: adding the parenthesis for each select statement did the trick, Thanks!

Comment: Which method will be faster in terms of performance?